# Row aggregation by time based distance

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Cheers,
working on the Postgres table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  "id" serial,
  "sensorid" integer,
  "actorid" integer,
  "timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
)
```

with example data

```
id, sensorid, actorid, timestamp
1; 2267; 3023; "2013-07-09 12:20:06.446"
2; 2267; 3023; "2013-07-09 12:20:16.421"
3; 2267; 3023; "2013-07-09 12:20:30.661"
4; 2267; 3023; "2013-07-09 12:20:36.958"
5; 2267; 3023; "2013-07-09 12:20:49.508"
6; 2267; 3023; "2013-07-09 12:20:57.683"
7; 3301; 3023; "2013-08-15 06:03:03.428"
8; 2267; 3024; "2013-07-09 12:19:52.196"
9; 2267; 3024; "2013-07-09 12:20:16.515"
10; 2267; 3024; "2013-07-09 12:20:42.341"
11; 2267; 3025; "2013-07-09 12:21:05.98"
12; 2268; 3026; "2013-07-09 12:22:35.03"
13; 2268; 3026; "2013-07-09 12:22:45.066"
14; 3192; 3026; "2013-08-09 07:41:31.206"
```

I want to group the records with the following criteria

1. They have the same sensorid
2. They have the same actorid
3. (The problem:) The timespan between each of them is less than (say) 5 minutes. That is, there might be a group that spans over more than an hour but there is never more than 5 minutes between two records in the group. The timespan may be aggregates as average.
4. Additionally, the number of aggregated records for each group must be given, since too large groups must be identified.

So, the output should look something like

```
id; sensorid, actorid, avg, count
1; 2267; 3023; "2013-07-09 12:20:30.000"; 7;
2; 3301; 3023; "2013-08-15 06:03:03.428"; 1;
3; 2267; 3024; "2013-07-09 12:20:06.415"; 3;
5; 2267; 3025; "2013-07-09 12:21:05.98"; 1;
6; 2268; 3026; "2013-07-09 12:22:40.626"; 2;
7; 3192; 3026; "2013-08-09 07:41:31.206"; 1;
```

Thanks for your help! 
Dennis

Comment: you should accept gordon-linoff answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to use `lag()` to determine the previous time is and whether it starts a new period.  Then for each sensorid/actorid combination, you can do a cumulative sum of `isStart` to identify the groups for each pair.

Then do the aggregation including this new group in the result:

```
select sensorid, actorid, min(timestamp), max(timestamp), count(*) as numInGroup
from (select t.*,
             sum(isStart) over (partition by sensorid, actorid order by timestamp) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when prevts is null or prevts < timestamp - interval '5 minutes'
                         then 1 else 0
                    end) as isStart
            from (select t.*,
                         lag(timestamp) over (partition by sensorid, actorid
                                              order by timestamp) as prevts
                  from my_table t
                 ) t
           ) t
     ) t
group by sensorid, actorid, grp
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, I did not test it sufficiently yet but it looks perfect right now (apart from a little typo in the line including the lag-function call [timestmp!=timestamp]). Apparently, I am getting even better results than I expected. The additional timespan offers great opportunities for further analysis. Thanks for your reply!